# closing an infowindow in an external div google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Updated to show all code of the page and final solution**

I'm creating a google maps infowindow that populates a dive fixed to the right of the screen. I have it so only one infowindow is open at a time, but I cannot seem to close the infowindow. I'm pulling the markers and the infowindow contents in with an array. Here is my code:

```
    jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).hide();
    jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).hide();
    var map;
    var overlay;
    USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsVisible = false;
    // Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var styles = [ {
            featureType: "all",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "simplified" }
            ]
            },{
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "on" }
            ]
            },{
            featureType: "labels.text",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "off" }
            ]
            },{
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "geometry",
            stylers: [
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: "simplified" }
            ]
            },{
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "o0" }
            ]
        }
    ];
    //  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($('<div id="infowindow"/>')[0]);
        var markers = new Array();

        locations = [
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 1st floor of the Student Services Center<br>(SSC)', 'restrooms', 35.188407, -101.847188, 4, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 2nd floor of the Student Services Center<br>(SSC)', 'restrooms', 35.188420, -101.847323, 5, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 2nd floor of the College Union Building<br>(CUB)', 'restrooms', 35.187952, -101.846269, 6, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 1st floor of Ordway Hall<br>(ORD)', 'restrooms', 35.188754, -101.848020, 7, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 1st floor of Ordway Hall<br>(ORD)', 'restrooms', 35.188759, -101.847878, 8, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 1st floor of Dutton Hall<br>(DUTT)', 'restrooms', 35.188903, -101.847750, 9, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Restrooms located on the 2nd floor of Dutton Hall<br>(DUTT)', 'restrooms', 35.188868, -101.847720, 10, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Men\'s Restroom located on the 1st and 2nd floors of Durrett Hall<br>(DUR)', 'restrooms', 35.188796, -101.846931, 11, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets-men.png"],
            ['Restrooms', 'Women\'s Restroom located on the 1st and 2nd floors of Durrett Hall<br>(DUR)', 'restrooms', 35.188796, -101.846553, 12, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/toilets-women.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 6<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.188878, -101.843967, 3, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 9<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.187010, -101.845769, 2, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 10<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.186830, -101.847218, 1, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 1<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.190173, -101.847839, 13, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 2<br />Temporary and ADA parking. No sticker required', 'parking', 35.189050, -101.847571, 14, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'ADA Accessible Parking', 'parking', 35.188969, -101.846949, 15, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking_disabled.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 3<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.189642, -101.846635, 16, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 4<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.189432, -101.845564, 45, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 5<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.188998, -101.845323, 46, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 8<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.188033, -101.845189, 47, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],
            ['Parking', 'Parking Lot 7<br />No sticker required', 'parking', 35.188337, -101.844390, 48, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/parking.png"],


            ['<h3>Amarillo College - Testing Services</h3>', '<h5>1st Floor of the Student Services Center(SSC-101)</h5><p>The Testing Center is a unit of the Amarillo College Student Affairs Division. The Testing Center supports instruction, academic planning, and the community by providing various testing services for prospective students, current students and members of the community.</p>', 'testing', 35.188297, -101.846933, 40, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac-sm.png"],
            ['Bookstore', '1st Floor of the College Union Building(CUB)<br />', 'bookstore', 35.187776, -101.846214, 41, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac-sm.png"],
            ['<h3>Advising and Counseling<h3>', '<h5>1st Floor of the Student Services Center(SSC-130)</h5><p>Amarillo College considers academic advising essential to student success.  The goal of the Advising Department is to help students identify their goals, and to help students achieve those goals.  As a returning, current, or prospective student, it\'s important to build a relationship with an academic advisor.</p>', 'advising', 35.188482, -101.847017, 42, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac-sm.png"],
            ['Financial Aid', '2nd Floor of the Student Services Center(SSC-210)<br />', 'financial', 35.188379, -101.847163, 43, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac-sm.png"],
            ['Registrar', '1st Floor of the Student Services Center(SSC)<br />', 'registrar', 35.188364, -101.847523, 44, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac-sm.png"],


            ['<h4>Lynn Library</h4>', '<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-433230"><ol class="carousel-indicators"><li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-433230"></li><li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-433230"></li><li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-433230"></li></ol><div class="carousel-inner"><div class="item active"><img alt="Carousel Bootstrap First" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-1600-500-1.jpg"/><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>First Thumbnail label</h4><p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p></div></div><div class="item"><img alt="Carousel Bootstrap Second" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-1600-500-2.jpg"/><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4><p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p></div></div><div class="item"><img alt="Carousel Bootstrap Third" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-1600-500-3.jpg"/><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4><p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p></div></div></div><a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-433230" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-433230" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></div></div></div></div><p>Lynn Library and the <a href="https://www.actx.edu/library/pagesmith/21" target="_blank">Student Computing Center</a> are located on the 4th floor of the Lynn Library building. They provide extensive resources and services for AC students and employees.</p><ul><li><strong>Research classes:</strong> Lynn Library has numerous online research databases that cover a wide range of topics. Library instructors teach information literacy/database demo classes when requested by faculty. For more information, contact <a href="mailto:e0400185@actx.edu">Emily Gilbert</a> via email or phone at <a href="tel:806-371-5403">806-371-5403</a>.</li></ul><ul> <li><strong>Individual research help:</strong> Librarians and other trained staff work individually with students to find appropriate resources for assignments. Library instructors also work with faculty and staff who want to learn more about using the Library&rsquo;s resources effectively. Instruction can be customized by discipline. Call <a href="tel:806-371-5468">806-371-5468</a> or toll-free at <a href="https://www.actx.edu/library/866-371-5468">866-371-5468</a> for more information.</li></ul><ul><li><strong><a href="https://www.actx.edu/library/pagesmith/21" target="_blank">Student Computing Center</a>: </strong>Employees are available to help students with computer matters. Printing is available at 5 cents per page. Two-sided printing is available for documents that allow it. Wi-Fi is available for people affiliated with AC.</li></ul><ul> <li><strong>Study areas: </strong>The 4th floor has many study tables and two group computer collaboration stations.</li></ul>', 'buildings', 35.187797, -101.847094, 17, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Ordway Hall', '', 'buildings', 35.188526, -101.847976, 18, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Dutton Hall', '', 'buildings', 35.188832, -101.847606, 19, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Engineering Building', '', 'buildings', 35.188526, -101.846436, 20, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Durrett Hall', '', 'buildings', 35.188832, -101.846723, 21, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Russell Hall', '', 'buildings', 35.187797, -101.848011, 22, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Student Services Center', '', 'buildings', 35.188362, -101.847142, 23, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['College Union Building', '', 'buildings', 35.187797, -101.846366, 24, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Experimental Theatre', '', 'buildings', 35.188536, -101.845950, 25, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Concert Hall/Theater', '', 'buildings', 35.188699, -101.845603, 26, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Music Building', '', 'buildings', 35.188427, -101.845423, 27, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Amarillo Museum of Art', '', 'buildings', 35.188572, -101.845091, 28, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Warren Hall', '', 'buildings', 35.187884, -101.845795, 29, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Parcells Hall', '', 'buildings', 35.187008, -101.846520, 30, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['R.E. Byrd Business Building', '', 'buildings', 35.187129, -101.847129, 31, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Carter Fitness Center', '', 'buildings', 35.186944, -101.848002, 32, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Gilvin Broadcast Center', '', 'buildings', 35.186668, -101.846512, 33, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Science Lab Building', '', 'buildings', 35.187711, -101.845347, 34, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Amarillo Bible Chair', '', 'buildings', 35.186381, -101.845816, 35, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Bible Chair of the Southwest', '', 'buildings', 35.189461, -101.846817, 36, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Baptist Bible Chair', '', 'buildings', 35.189613, -101.844177, 37, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Amarillo Opera', '', 'buildings', 35.187619, -101.844515, 38, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Science Lab Building', '', 'buildings', 35.187711, -101.845347, 39, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
            ['Facilities Management Center', '', 'buildings', 35.191598, -101.848251, 40, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"]



            ];
        buildings = [

                    ['Lynn Library', '', 'buildings', '35.187797, -101.847094', 17, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Ordway Hall', '', 'buildings', '35.188526, -101.847976', 18, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Dutton Hall', '', 'buildings', '35.188832, -101.847606', 19, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Engineering Building', '', 'buildings', '35.188526, -101.846436', 20, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Durrett Hall', '', 'buildings', '35.188832, -101.846723', 21, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Russell Hall', '', 'buildings', '35.187797, -101.848011', 22, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Student Services Center', '', 'buildings', '35.188362, -101.847142', 23, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['College Union Building', '', 'buildings', '35.187797, -101.846366', 24, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Experimental Theatre', '', 'buildings', '35.188536, -101.845950', 25, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Concert Hall/Theater', '', 'buildings', '35.188699, -101.845603', 26, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Music Building', '', 'buildings', '35.188427, -101.845423', 27, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Amarillo Museum of Art', '', 'buildings', '35.188572, -101.845091', 28, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Warren Hall', '', 'buildings', '35.187884, -101.845795', 29, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Parcells Hall', '', 'buildings', '35.187008, -101.846520', 30, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['R.E. Byrd Business Building', '', 'buildings', '35.187129, -101.847129', 31, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Carter Fitness Center', '', 'buildings', '35.186944, -101.848002', 32, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Gilvin Broadcast Center', '', 'buildings', '35.186668, -101.846512', 33, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Science Lab Building', '', 'buildings', '35.187711, -101.845347', 34, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Amarillo Bible Chair', '', 'buildings', '35.186381, -101.845816', 35, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Bible Chair of the Southwest', '', 'buildings', '35.189461, -101.846817', 36, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Baptist Bible Chair', '', 'buildings', '35.189613, -101.844177', 37, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Amarillo Opera', '', 'buildings', '35.187619, -101.844515', 38, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Science Lab Building', '', 'buildings', '35.187711, -101.845347', 39, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"],
                    ['Facilities Management Center', '', 'buildings', '35.191598, -101.848251', 40, "http://www.actx.edu/staff/images/icons/ac.png"]


                    ];
        var minZoomLevel = 18;  
        var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
                    {name: "Styled Map"});
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            minZoom: 7,
            maxZoom: 21,
            tilt:0,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.188435, -101.845448),
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADS, 'map_style']
            }
        };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
      directionsDisplay.setOptions({suppressInfoWindows: true});


    // geolocation stuff  


      if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                               position.coords.longitude);        


            }, function() {
              handleNoGeolocation(true);
            });
          } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleNoGeolocation(false);
          }

      map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

      var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(35.186065, -101.848535);
      var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(35.191990, -101.843090);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);


      var srcImage = 'https://www.actx.edu/staff/images/Washington-Campus-New_trans9.png';
    //  srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

      // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
      // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
      overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

      infocanvas = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



      var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]),
      map: map,
      store_id: locations[i][5],
      icon: locations[i][6]
          });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).css('visibility','visible');      
        jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).css('visibility','visible');
        jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).show();
        jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).show();   
        jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).empty();
        jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).append( locations[i][0]+"<br />"+locations[i][1] );
  }
})(marker, i));
markers.push(marker);       
  }

var closeInfocanvasX = document.getElementById('close-infocanvas-x');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeInfocanvasX, 'click', closeInfocanvas);

function closeInfocanvas() {
    jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).hide();
    jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).hide(); 
}

            // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
              function show(category) {
                for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
                  if (locations[i][2] == category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                  }
                }
              }

              // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
              function hide(category) {
                for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
                  if (locations[i][2] == category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(false);
                  }
                }
              }

              // == show or hide the categories initially ==
             hide("parking");
             hide("restrooms");
             hide("testing");
             hide("bookstore");
             hide("advising");
             hide("financial");
             hide("registrar");
             hide("buildings");




                $(".checkbox").click(function(){
                    var cat = $(this).attr("value");

                    // If checked
                    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                    {
                        show(cat);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hide(cat);
                    }
                  });

    }

    function calcRoute() {

        var mode;
        switch (document.getElementById("mode").value) {
          case "bicycling":
            mode = google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING;
            break;
          case "driving":
            mode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
            break;
          case "walking":
            mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
            break;
        }

          var start = pos;
          var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
          var request = {
            origin: pos,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: mode

          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
          });
        }




    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
          if (errorFlag) {
            var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
          } else {
            var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
          }

          var options = {
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.188435, -101.845448),
            content: content
          };

          var infocanvas = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
          map.setCenter(options.position);
        }

    // [END region_initialization]

    // [START region_constructor]
    /** @constructor */
    function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

      // Initialize all properties.
      this.bounds_ = bounds;
      this.image_ = image;
      this.map_ = map;

      // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
      // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
      // method so we'll leave it null for now.
      this.div_ = null;

      // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
      this.setMap(map);
    }
    // [END region_constructor]

    // [START region_attachment]
    /**
     * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
     * added to the map.
     */
    USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
      div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
      div.style.position = 'absolute';

      // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = '100%';
      img.style.height = '100%';
      img.style.position = 'absolute';
      div.appendChild(img);

      this.div_ = div;

      // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
    };
    // [END region_attachment]

    // [START region_drawing]
    USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

      // We use the south-west and north-east
      // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
      // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

      // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
      // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
      // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
      var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

      // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    };
    // [END region_drawing]

    // [START region_removal]
    // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
    // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
    USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
      this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
      this.div_ = null;
    };
    // [END region_removal]

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here is the relevant html:

```
<div id="close-infocanvas" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
<div id="close-infocanvas-x"><a href="#" class="show_hide"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x"></i></a></div></div>
<div id="infocanvas" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "closing an infowindow in an external div"?  An infowindow (at least a [google.maps.InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)) only appears on a map.

Comment: `infocanvas.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion about infowindow. You defined a new infowindow named "infocanvas" but then you want to close the infowindow named "infowindow". When in reality you're working with a simple DIV.

In the event listener "map, click" just hide the DIV infocanvas like you did in the top of your code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {    
    jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).hide();
    jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).hide();
});
```

One more thing, var map should be out of the initialize function. Only:

```
 var map;
```

and then inside the function "initialize" you define the value of this variable

```
map = new google.maps.Map (document.getElementById ("map-canvas'), MapOptions);
```

without the word "var".

So the variable "map" will be available in any part of your code.
At this point the code in line 343 can't access the variable "map".

"var markers" should also be out of the initialize function and you must create a specific function to add markers to the map.

Summarizing the "initialize" function must be minimized by subdividing the code into smaller functions. That way you organize your code and becomes much easier to detect errors.

You will find more info about this in [maps with multiple markers](http://en.marnoto.com/2013/12/mapa-com-varios-marcadores-google-maps.html).

Comment: I see what I did wrong there. Let me post my entire code. Your explanation allowed me to close the infocanvas div/infowindow, but i am generating multiple markers by category and the new infowindows do not appear.

code posted above, reflecting your changes.

Comment: I've added the following:

`jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).show();`
`jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).show();`

That makes the infowindow reappear when i click another marker. However I only want to close the infowindow from the infowindow with an X or a button. I need to call it explicitly for that one spot only and not by just clicking on the map.

but I am closer. :)

Comment: got it! added the following to finish it up: `var closeInfocanvasX = document.getElementById('close-infocanvas-x');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeInfocanvasX, 'click', closeInfocanvas);

function closeInfocanvas() {

//    infocanvas = null;
 jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).hide();
 jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).hide();
 /*jQuery( '#infocanvas' ).show();
 jQuery( '#close-infocanvas' ).show();   */
 
}`

Comment: Thanks for the help! somewhat final product can be seen at the link above, and I've edited the code to reflect the changes suggested and what i came up with.